# Get new position x distance away from another position using a slope

Tags: math, plot, lua

Excuse me if I phrased the title wrong, I am not great with math and don't know the right term, but I figure someone will edit it correctly.

I am creating a script in Lua and I have a target location and my location. I found the slope for it so at the moment I have X1, X2, Y1, Y2, and M(slope).
I do not know the math to add a new point with x distance away.

Sort of like this badly done MS paint example where the 2 black dots are target on the far right, and my location on the left, and then the green dot is what I want.

[image: Plotted dots]

Comment: x distance away from a point is a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that

1. The black point on the left is (X1, Y1)
2. The black point on the right is (X2, Y2)
3. The slope M = (Y2 – Y1)/(X2 - X1)

This means that the straight line between (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2) are all the points (X,Y) where

```
Y = Y1 + M (X-X1)
```

Define the distance D between (X1, Y1) and (X2, Y2), which is given by

```
D = Math.sqrt((X2 - X1)² + (Y2 – Y1)²)
```

where `Math.sqrt(...)` is the square root function.  If you want a point on that straight line to be a distance `d` from (X1, Y1) then there are two such points, one to the left of (X1, Y1) and one to the right of (X1, Y1).  The coordinates of those two points are

```
(X1 + (X2 - X1) d/D, Y1 + (Y2 - Y1) d/D)
```

and

```
(X1 - (X2 - X1) d/D, Y1 - (Y2 - Y1) d/D)
```

The first point, with the `+` sign, is the point that's a distance `d` from (X1, Y1) in the direction of (X2, Y2).  The second point with the `-` sign, is the point that's a distance `d` from (X1, Y1) but in the direction away from (X2, Y2).  If the case you want is always as shown in the diagram, then the answer is always to take the second point with the `-` sign.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine two formula.

```
1. (y3-y2)^2 + (x3-x2)^2 = d
2. (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) = (y3-y2)/(x3-x2)
```

This is haskell code for your question. it maybe usefull.

```
foo x1 y1 x2 y2 d =
    [(x3,y3) |
    x3 <- [-100..100], y3 <- [-100..100],
    (y3-y2)^2 + (x3-x2)^2 == d,
    (y2-y1)/(x2-x1) == (y3-y2)/(x3-x2)]
```

ps: 100 is a range. you can change it. this function return two couple. like (-1,1), (11,9). because I dont specify the way.

Another solution:(I combined formulas)

```
let k = d / sqrt((y2-y1)^2 + (x2-x1)^2)

x3 = x2 + k * (x2-x1)   other   x3 = x2 - k * (x2-x1)
y3 = y2 + k * (y2-y1)   other   y3 = y2 - k * (y2-y1)
```

Comment: If this does answer the question, it's so unclear that I can't figure it out what you're trying to say.  And what about the distance `x`?  There are a lot of 1s and 2s in this answer and distinguishing them is very context dependent.